# Firebase updateting user Profile display name Not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am not able to update user display name in firebase for a User .Here is my code .

```
$("[purpose=sign_up]").click(function(){
      var email=$("#email").val().trim();
      var password=$("#password").val().trim();
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user){
        var display_nam=document.getElementById("company_name").value;
        console.log(display_nam);

        return user.updateProfile({'displayName': display_nam});
      }).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

what's the sdk version you are using? If the version >= 5.0, createUserWithEmailAndPassword returns a promise of UserCredential. You'll need to get the user reference by doing `UserCredential.user`.